# Regex to remove some special character occurring multiple times in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string as following in JavaScript:

```
"[
\"\\"[[\\"leadOwnerKey\\",\\"Suyog\\",\\"Praneet\\"],
[\\"Open\\",\\"1\\",\\"1\\"],
[\\"Total count\\",\\"1\\",\\"1\\"]]\\"\"
]"
```

I have to remove all occurrences of `\` and `"` but have to keep all occurrences of `[` , `]` and `,`.

can anyone suggest regex for it?
OR
Is there any other way to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str = str.replace(/[\\"]/g, '');
```

Outputs:

```
[
[[leadOwnerKey,Suyog,Praneet],
[Open,1,1],
[Total count,1,1]]
]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0mtL3oyu/